# How can I merge multi photos with duration and export them as a video

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

how i can make a slide show for multi images with duration
I want to enter multiple images to the code and export a video
I only found this package [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) and used it as follows
But I'm having a problem
1- In merging several photos
2- Put a duration between them

the images with path like this

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/01.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Download/02.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Download/03.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Download/04.jpg
```

my code is

```
Future<void> VideoMerger() async {
    loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    if(await Permission.storage.request().isGranted){
      String commandToExecute ='-r 15 -f mp3 -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/khh.mp3 -f image2 -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/01.jpg -y /storage/emulated/0/Download/output.mp4';
      await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(commandToExecute).then((rc) {
        loading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        print('FFmpeg process exited with rc: $rc');
      });
    }else if (await Permission.storage.isPermanentlyDenied){
      loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      openAppSettings();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a package `carousel_slider 4.1.1`.

Add `carousel_slider: ^4.1.1` to your pubspec.yaml dependencies. And import it:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
```

To use
Simply create a CarouselSlider widget, and pass the required params:

```
CarouselSlider(
options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
return Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber
      ),
      child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
    );
   },
  );
 }).toList(),
)
```

Params:

```
CarouselSlider(
items: items,
options: CarouselOptions(
  height: 400,
  aspectRatio: 16/9,
  viewportFraction: 0.8,
  initialPage: 0,
  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
  reverse: false,
  autoPlay: true,
  autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
  autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  enlargeCenterPage: true,
  onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 )
)
```

More details [here](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I want to combine photos into a video
The package used is for the video
I want to enter multiple images to the code and export a video

Answer (score 0):

use [carousel_clider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package

Try this:

```
var items = ["image_1", "image_2", "image_3"];
CarouselSlider(
   items: items,
   options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 400,
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      reverse: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I want to combine photos into a video
The package used is for the video
I want to enter multiple images to the code and export a video